# dynamic element and jquery ui (draggable)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am creating dynamic elements for dragging and placing elements on a positioned absolute basis using percentage. The issue is, that as I add more dynamic elements the dragging snaps the image over by 2% for each addition except the first one created...

Here is the codepen link.
https://codepen.io/designsbycamaron/pen/yLPmNXx

Code for just the draggable.

```
$(".img_overlay").draggable({
          containment: "#bkg-area",
          stop: function () {
            var offset = $("#bkg-area").offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            var l =
              100 *
                parseFloat(
                  $(this).position().left / parseFloat($("#bkg-area").width())
                ) +
              "%";
            var t =
              100 *
                parseFloat(
                  $(this).position().top / parseFloat($("#bkg-area").height())
                ) +
              "%";
            $('input[name="pos_x_' + $(this).attr("store-data") + '"]').val(
              l
            );
            $('input[name="pos_y_' + $(this).attr("store-data") + '"]').val(
              t
            );
            $(this).css("left", l);
            $(this).css("top", t);
          }
        });
```

Comment: Might be a strange relationship between your newly created items and the draggable init. Please clarify how we use the code pen to replicate the issue.

Comment: Add an image to the first input. Then another image, and then another image to the same absolute input. Move the first one around, and then the second and you will see the issue.